# Swedish characters in Databin

Tags: character-encoding, databin

I want to store strings with Swedish characters like å, ä and ö in a Databin, but get the following result:

```
bin = CreateDatabin[];
DatabinUpload[bin, {"a", "ä"}];
Values[bin]
{a,"a""}
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Please report that. Meanwhile you can store compressed values: `DatabinUpload[bin, Compress /@ {"a", "ä"}]; Uncompress /@ Values[bin]`

Comment: Thanks. I have reported the bug, and the solution you suggest works.